# How should I access the args of a Splash request when parsing the response on a 400 error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapy-splash

I'm sending through some arguments to a Splash endpoint from a Scrapy crawler to be used by a Splash script that will be run. Sometimes errors may occur in that script. For runtime errors I use `pcall` to wrap the questionable script so I can gracefully catch and return run time errors. For syntax errors however, this doesn't work and instead a 400 error is thrown. I set my crawler to handle such an errors with the `handle_httpstatus_list` attribute, so my parse callback is being called on such an error, where I can inspect what went wrong gracefully.

So far so good, except since I couldn't handle the syntax error gracefully in the lua script I wasn't able to return some of the input Splash args that the callback will be expecting to access. Right now I'm calling `response._splash_args()` on the `SplashJsonResponse` object that I do have and this is allowing me to access those values. However this is essentially a protected method which means it might not be a long term solution.

Is there a better way to access the Splash args in the response when you can't rely on the associated splash script running at all?